# How to do color correction when mosaicing and clipping with gdalwarp

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, color, mosaic, histogram

I'm mosaicing a number of GeoTiffs with `gdalwarp` and clipping to a geojson area of interest using the following command:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline <PATH_TO_GEOJSON> -crop_to_cutline -overwrite <PATHS_TO_INPUT_GEOTIFFS> <PATH_TO_OUTPUT_GEOTIFF>
```

Doing this, I end up with segments where the colors don't match up. See below:
[image]

Is there a way to do histogram matching or another color correction technique to reduce these artifacts?

I have a couple of requirements: (1) I need to be able to do this programatically, (2) I would prefer to use a gdal tool, (3) the files can get quite big (for example, `gdal_merge.py` claims it would need more disk space than is available to create a mosaic.

Comment: As far as I know GDAL does not have ready made tools for histogram matching. OSSIM seems to have https://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki/histogram_operations.

Comment:   trying to avoid OSSIM if possible since the build/install/configuration is painful (and the process for machine setup needs to be easily repeatable).

Comment: There used to be Opticks but the project is either moved or dead http://www.webmap.ca/Opticks. But OSSIM developers are responsive, perhaps they can help you with building and you can help them by telling about your pain. An option is to balance the appearance of the source images with Photoshop etc. before making a mosaic but I guess that you want to have an automatic system.